# How to use groupby() function in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, pandas-groupby

What does the `frame` variable signify in this code?

```
for group, frame in df.groupby('STNAME'):
    avg = np.average(frame['CENSUS2010POP'])
    print('Counties in state ' + group + ' have an average population of ' + str(avg))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`frame` here is sub_group, since you `groupby` `STNAME`

So the for loop here is equal to

```
for x in df['STNAME'].unique():
   frame=df[df.STNAME==x]
   avg = np.average(frame['CENSUS2010POP'])
```